# How to fit a Tikz picture into a tabularx cell?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tabularx

I am trying to put a Tikz picture into a cell of a tabularx. The problem is that it doesn't fit in my cell. Here is the code :

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{17cm}{|c|c|X|X|}

    \hline
    Solide & Expression & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Ordre de grandeur} \\ \hline\hline

    Barre homogene & \multirow{3}{*}{$J_{\Delta} = \frac{1}{3}Ma^2$} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Branche} \\ \cline{1-1}\cline{3-4}

\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [ultra thick] (-3,0)--(3,0) node [midway, below left] {$G$} ;
    \draw (0,0) node{$\bullet$} ;
    \draw [<->] (0,-0.5)--(3,-0.5) node [midway, below] {$a$} ;
    \draw [dashed] (0,-1.5)--(0,1.5) node [near end, above right] {$\Delta$};
    \end{tikzpicture}} & & $M=500g$ & $a=50cm$ \\ \cline{3-4}

    & & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{$4,2\times 10^{-2}$ $m^2.kg$} \\ \hline\hline

\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: Do you want to make the cell bigger of the tikzplot smaller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than make the `\multirow` bigger, I made the rows next to it bigger.

[image: multirow image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}

\newsavebox{\tempbox}

\begin{document}

\savebox{\tempbox}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [ultra thick] (-3,0)--(3,0) node [midway, below left] {$G$} ;
    \draw (0,0) node{$\bullet$} ;
    \draw [<->] (0,-0.5)--(3,-0.5) node [midway, below] {$a$} ;
    \draw [dashed] (0,-1.5)--(0,1.5) node [near end, above right] {$\Delta$};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{tabularx}{17cm}{|c|c|X|X|}

    \hline
    Solide & Expression & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Ordre de grandeur} \\ \hline\hline

    Barre homogene & \multirow{8}{*}{$J_{\Delta} = \frac{1}{3}Ma^2$} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Branche} \\ \cline{1-1}\cline{3-4}

    \multirow{2}{*}[4ex]{\usebox{\tempbox}} &\rule[\dimexpr 1ex-0.25\ht\tempbox]{0pt}{0.5\ht\tempbox} & $M=500g$ & $a=50cm$ \\ \cline{3-4}

    & & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\rule[\dimexpr 1ex-0.25\ht\tempbox]{0pt}{0.5\ht\tempbox}$4,2\times 10^{-2}$ $m^2.kg$} \\ \hline\hline

\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!  Therefore, how could I vertically center the text in columns 2,3 and 4 ?

Comment: The optional argument for \rule will lower (or raise) the baseline.  I'll try to center everything.

Comment: One could also use \raisebox to achieve this effect.  For example, \raisebox{-1ex}[0.25\ht\tempbox][0.25\ht\tempbox]{$M=500g$}